# Websocket lifecycle in Android's applications

Tags: android, websocket, android-lifecycle

I'm using websocket (socketIO) on my app for a notification center. It Will be reopened everytime the app come to foreground, but when It goes on background the webSocket remains open, unless I Kill the app on task manager. How to link the webSocket lifecycle only when the app is active on foreground? Actually I've a Singleton pattern to get only a connection to the websocket, but i can't understand when the app goes on background, and bind the disconnect on `onDestroy` of the main App isn't enough, the high-end devices keep the app in background days if someone doesn't kill them.